# i tried change javascript to jquery, but it has problom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change javascript to jquery but it doesn't work!
especially the value part is difficult to me!

javascript

```
function javascript_click() {
  if(document.getElementById("value1").value){
    var val = document.getElementById("value1").value;
    if(document.getElementById(val)){
      //var myNodelist = document.getElementById("val").value;
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "선택하신아이디는 " + val + " 이며 id갯수는 1개입니다.By javascript <br>";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML += "wrong value of ID <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

this is jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#javascript_click').click(function() {
    if ($("#value1").val()) {
      var val = $("#value1").val();
      if ($("val")) {
        $("#cnt").html("노드 갯수 : " + length)
      }
      else{
        $("#cnt").html("wrong value ")
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This might be the problem $("val")

Comment: What do you mean with val?

Comment: You are using 'javascript_click' function as id in jQuery is this correct? share the jsfiddle link link it will easy for better understanding and then you are using 'val' as string use val instead of 'val'

Comment: Several little things are wrong with this code and show that you probably don't understand some of the jQuery basics. I would highly suggest a quick course/tutorial.

Comment: i think this part has a problem. [var val = document.getElementById("value1").value;
        if(document.getElementById(val))] ->var val = $("#value1").val();
 if("#val"){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **javascript_click** function in JQuery format:

```
function javascript_click() {
if ($("#value1").val()) {
    var val=$("#value1").val();
    if($('#'+val).length){
         $("#cnt").html($("#cnt").html()+"선택하신아이디는 " + val + " 이며 id갯수는 1개입니다.By javascript <br>");
    }else{
         $("#cnt").html($("#cnt").html()+"wrong value of ID <br>");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your test `if($('#'+val))` will always deliver a `true` result, as it will always produce a jquery object. What you probably *want* to test is, whether there are matched elements in the jquery object. You would do that with `if($('#'+val).length)`.

Comment: thanks @cars10m for the clarification `if($('#'+val).length)` is good but with `if($('#'+val))` it will not return true always. It will return true if it matches the selector.

Comment: I beg to disagree with you: take `$('#nonsense').length`. It will result in `0`, as no element with this ID exists on the current page. But `$('#nonsense')` will result in a valid jquery object. Testing this object in an `if` clause will return a "truesy" response. To clarify things:  `!!$('#nonsense')` will always give `true`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tuhin Hossain has already delivered the main points. You can however shorten the code a little bit further like if you like. Here is a working fiddle:

```js
$('#javascript_click').click(function() {
  var val=$("#value1").val();
  $("#cnt").append( (val && $('#'+val).length)
     ?"선택하신아이디는 " + $('#'+val).val() + " 이며 id갯수는 1개입니다.By javascript <br>"
     :"wrong value of ID <br>"
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" placeholder="enter a valid ID here" id="value1">
<input type="button" id="javascript_click" value="click me">
<br>one <input id="one" type="text" value="1">
<br>two <input id="two" type="text" value="number 2">
<br>three <input id="three" type="text" value="the third one">
<br>four <input id="four" type="text" value="fourth">
<br>five <input id="five" type="text" value="and the fifth">
<br><br>
<div id="cnt">This is the div I want to add to ...<br></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
var length = val.length
```

your val is an javascript object.